# bpopup plugin associates one div element in looped PHP script

Tags: php, joomla, bpopup

I am using bpopup with multiple popup links on the page and multiple content for each link. To associate the JQuery with each link, I use a [id^="div_name"]. The JS is given below:-

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    console.log( 'ready!' );
    $('[id^="click"]').bind('click', function(){
    $('[id^="profile"]').css('display','inline');
    $('[id^="profile"]').bPopup({
       modalClose: true
      , opacity: .8
      , positionStyle: 'fixed' 
      , fadeSpeed: 'slow'
      , followSpeed: 'slow'
      });
   });
});
```

The corresponding PHP script has:-

```
<?php
foreach($listings as $listing)
{   
        <a id="click" href="some url"><?php echo $listing->profile_link;?></a>
        <div id="profile" style="background-color:#fff; width:400px; height:400px; display:none; "><?php echo $listing->company_name; ?></div>
     }
```

The listings are all being associated with the popup action. However, their content is the same as the last `$listings->company_name`. However, I want the content to have individual company names. I realize that I am using the same div-id and after the content is being rendered on the browser, it associates the last one to all the popups. How do I work around this?